# iOS - How to slow down UISlider animation?

Tags: ios, uislider, uiviewanimation

I'm trying to slow down the animation of the UISlider when changing values.

So far, I've tried the old UIView animation method:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"slider" context:nil];

[UIView setAnimationDuration:5.0];
[self.slider setValue:2 animated:YES];

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

And the new blocks based method:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:5.0 
         animations:^{
            [self.slider setValue:2 animated:YES];
                 }];
```

I've tried with and without the `animated:YES` value set. In all cases, the slider simply animates at the default speed.

Is there another tactic I should be looking at to customize the speed of the animation?

Should I subclass the slider and override anything there?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [OBSlider](http://oleb.net/blog/2011/01/obslider-a-uislider-subclass-with-variable-scrubbing-speed/), a UISlider subclass with variable scrubbing speed (as seen in the iPod app on iOS) by [Ole Begemann](https://stackoverflow.com/users/116862/ole-begemann). I'm not saying it is exactly what you want but you can see how it is implemented since [the code is hosted at GitHub](https://github.com/ole/OBSlider). Basically, it subclasses `UISlider` and overrides the touch tracking methods:

- `beginTrackingWithTouch:withEvent:`
- `continueTrackingWithTouch:withEvent:`
- `endTrackingWithTouch:withEvent:`