# iOS - How to slow down UISlider at particular value

Tags: ios, uislider

I am working on a customise UISlider where the MinimumValue is 0 and MaximumValue is 100. I want user to slow down the speed at the value of 50. For an example , if a user start sliding from 0 to 100 , it should work in a normal speed from 0-50 and then there should be a speed break at 50 and then the normal speed should be continued form 51-100.

Currently i have tried UISlider step size,

```
-(IBAction)valueChanged:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Value : %f",roundf(_questionSlider.value));
    float newStep = roundf((_questionSlider.value) / self.stepValue);

    self.questionSlider.value = newStep * self.stepValue;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by a "slow down"? Do you want the thumb to actually slow down as the user drags the thumb or do you want a wider range of the slider to give a value of 50?

Comment: @rmaddy just to reduce the speed at "50" and give a feel to the user that you have reached a significant value.

Comment: How about adding a "detent" at 50? Instead of attempting to change the speed, you make the thumb seems to stick a bit at 50.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6311354/ios-how-to-slow-down-uislider-animation

Comment: @rmaddy Thank you but any ideas of adding a detent to UISlider ?